# My application uses Pinterest api not working today?

Tags: pinterest

My application is not working today
it's an error message: `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`
and I try to use link : `https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/`
to debug.
 but Response error:`Something went wrong, are your fields correct?`
Is Pinterest blocking this feature?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking if the pinterest api is down?

Comment: i can't use any api from pinterest

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It seems like Pinterest is banning all tokens generated outside an App (using the access token generator tool).

Please refer to [Token Debugger Tool](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/token-debugger/) and see if your token is banned.

I think they are pushing us to create an App in fufilment of new privacy policies.

Comment: Checkout the documentation for how to generate a token as well: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, please help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150697/generate-pinterest-access-token-dynamically-with-php-api?s=1|0.0000